# Libgdx SpriteBatch won't position correctly on Screen

Tags: android, css, libgdx, sprite

I have been trying to position my spritebatch correctly regardless of screen size but it simply wont scale..This is what I want to achieve on every screen size..I want my Sprite Object to be positioned at the center of the x-axis on every screen size and on the first half of the screen (above dotted line) and have it scale as well..I have also noticed that spritebatch doesn't respect my gameheight and gamewidth instead opting for screenwidth and screenheight. The dimensions for my sprite anim are 900 by 700 and I am hoping it can scale for lower resolutions

Code :

`batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 20, app.midPointY + 350, app.screenWidth, 465);`

[image]

Comment: for `batch.draw(Texture, x, y)`, you can do `batch.draw(mTexture, Gdx.graphics.getWidth / 2 - mTexture.getWidth / 2, desiredHeight);`

Comment: You should learn about Viewports: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports